# How to exclude values from a php array

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the following array in a WordPress query options which is used to output product categories, and I need to exclude certain values from it by category ID, how can I do so?

```
$args = apply_filters( 'storefront_product_categories_args', array(
            'limit'             => 12,
            'columns'           => 3,
            'child_categories'  => 0,
            'orderby'           => 'name',
            'order'             => 'asc',
            'title'             => __( '', 'storefront' ),
```

Many thanks.

Comment: The array items have no ID values, so this is impossible.

Comment: Also can you show what output you want and on what basis? also your code effort will also needed. Thanks

Comment: Looks like wordpress query options, in which case you want to add an element with the key `'exclude'` and the value a comma seperated string of ids, eg: `'exclude' => '1,46,92',`

Comment: @Steve, Yes, that's exactly what I am looking for, to exclude some elements from the query by their ID. I tried adding the code you suggested by it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Removing items from a PHP array by key is done using the `unset` function:

```
$array = array(
    'limit'             => 12,
    'columns'           => 3,
    'child_categories'  => 0,
    'orderby'           => 'name',
    'order'             => 'asc',
    'title'             => 'something',
);

unset( $array[ 'columns' ] );

var_dump( $array );
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I was thinking of adding something like, 'exclude' => '1,46,92', to exclude these values from the resulting display, but it's not working. Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong answer. Before your edit, I really thought this was what you needed. Your question is however more Wordpress related. I'm sorry I couldn't be of more help. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Rein,
I was hoping to remove the "on hold" status from my question so that more people can see it and may be offer some help
Do you know how can I do this?